# tesseract wrapper - slow performance

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

I'm using [tessearct wrapper for C#](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract) v3. What is needed is to get 12 digit number which is located at the top of an image. The following does the job, but very slow (42 seconds on my PC):

```
public string GetIdentityNumber(string path)
{
    string identityNum = string.Empty;
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"[\d]{4}\s+[\d]{4}\s+[\d]{4}");

    try
    {
        using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(@".\tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default))
        {
            using (var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(path))
            {
                using (var page = engine.Process(img, PageSegMode.SingleBlock))
                {
                    using (var iter = page.GetIterator())
                    {
                        string text;
                        Match match;
                        iter.Begin();
                        do
                        {
                            text = iter.GetText(PageIteratorLevel.TextLine);
                            match = regex.Match(text);
                            if (match.Success)
                            {
                                identityNum = match.ToString();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        while (iter.Next(PageIteratorLevel.TextLine));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    return identityNum;
}
```

It takes about 40 seconds to execute page.GetIterator() method. Does anyone know any settings or approaches to improve the performance?

Answer (score 0):

Other than restricting the image (basically cropping) to the area where you feel the text will be, so that there will be less to process, there's not a lot to do.

Tesseract is not known for its speed.